# Xamarin Forms image in ListView gives app poor performance

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have simple listview in Xamarin.Forms portable project. On Android Listview it is very slow if I put simple image in ViewCell and bind image with path. Image size is not grater than 10Kb. Application poor performance are visible on scrolling and also when I'm sliding menu (open/close). Situation is very same even on device as it is on emulator.

Here is my XAML code of listview

```
<ListView x:Name="newsList" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" RowHeight="70" SeparatorVisibility="None">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>           
        <Image HeightRequest="50" Aspect="AspectFill"   Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>      
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Application has simple Master Detail Page menu for navigation. I am binding 3-4 (testing) items to ListView and it is very very slow. I am using 2.2.0.31 version of Forms.

This is very strange because I don't have big dana in my ListVies.

Backend Code is very simply for testing:

```
public partial class News : ContentPage
{

    public List<Model.NewsData> NewsListData;
    public News()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NewsListData = new List<Model.NewsData>();
        TestData();
    }
    public void TestData()
    {
        NewsListData.Add(new Model.NewsData()
        {

            Image = "placeholdercircle.png",
            Title = "Some Stuff Here"
        });


        newsList.ItemsSource = NewsListData;
    }
}
```

Only thing I have on my News.xaml page is ListView. I'm using RoundedImage library but not in this list, and not on this view.

What am I doing wrong here, and why is my ListView so slow?

Answer (score 8):

On Android with Xamarin.Forms specifically, I had terrible performance problems with images.  It was caused by only having one size of image in the **Resources/drawable** folder of the Droid project whilst I was developing.

As soon as I put appropriately sized images into **drawable-hdpi,-mdpi,-xhdpi** etc., there was a huge performance increase.

Comment: Wow, it's like night and day performance. This should be added to Xamarin.Forms documentation if it isn't already.

Comment: Worked like charm